# How can I have 2 different types of Collections in the root of a a custom configuration section?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, web-config, app-config

I created my first custom configuration section and all went well. Then I went to extend it and it went sideways. The problem I have and cant find a lot of example on is that inside my Section, I want to have 2 different types of collections. The elements in both collections are totally different but the same in each. I cant get the Configuration Section to return the correct Collection as I get errors. I could cheat and create 2 sections but that doesnt seem like the correct way to implement this.

ok Some code

```
<configSections>
  <section name="MyFileSection" type="My.ConfigManager.MyFileListConfiguration, MyConfigManager" />
</configSections>
<MyFileSection>
  <MyDirectoryRootCollection>
    <add rootName="MyDataLocation"   rootLocation="\\MyServer\MyDirectory"/>
    <add rootName="YourDataLocation" rootLocation="\\YourServer\YourDirectory"/>
  </MyDirectoryRootCollection>
  <MyFileListCollection>
    <add keyName="MyFile1"   copyType="File" sourceFileName="TestFile1" />
    <add keyName="MyFile2"   copyType="FTP"  sourceFileName="TestFile2" />
    <add keyName="MyFile3"   copyType="File" sourceFileName="TestFile3" />
  </MyFileListCollection>
</MyFileSection>
```

So inside MyFileSection, I have 2 collections... MyDirectoryRootCollection and MyFileListCollection. I thought the one Config class would let me get the 2 of them like this.

```
namespace My.ConfigManager
{
    public class MyFileListConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
    {
        private static string sMyFileListCollectionConst      = "MyFileListCollection";
        private static string sMyDirectoryRootCollectionConst = "MyDirectoryRootCollection";


        [ConfigurationProperty("MyFileListCollection", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
        [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MyFileListConfigEleCollection), AddItemName = "MyFileListCollection")]
        public MyFileListConfigEleCollection MyFileListCollection
        {
            get { return ((MyFileListConfigEleCollection)(base["MyFileListCollection"])); }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("MyDirectoryRootCollection", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
        [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MyDirectoryRootConfigEleCollection), AddItemName = "MyFileListCollection")]
        public MyFileListConfiguration MyDirectoryRoot
        {
            get { return ((MyFileListConfiguration)(base["MyDirectoryRootCollection"])); }
        }

    }
```

I try and get the config section with this call

```
MyFileListConfiguration fileListSection = (MyFileListConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyFileSection");
```

but I get this Error -

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled
>   Message="The Configuration property 'MyDirectoryRootCollection' may
>   not be derived from ConfigurationSection."

Has anyone any ideas what I am doing wrong and is it possible to have 2 totally different collections inside a section?

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you.

**Usage:**

```
MyFileListConfiguration myConfig = (MyFileListConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyFileSection");

myConfig.Files[0] or myConfig.Files["MyFile1"] => .KeyName / .CopyType / .SourceFileName
        //  myConfig.Directories[0] or myConfig.Directories["MyDataLocation"] => .RootName / .RootLocation


public class MyFileListConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("MyFileListCollection", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    public MyFileListCollection Files
    {
        get { return ((MyFileListCollection)(base["MyFileListCollection"])); }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("MyDirectoryRootCollection", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    public MyDirCollection Directories
    {
        get { return ((MyDirCollection)(base["MyDirectoryRootCollection"])); }
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MyFileElement))]
public class MyFileListCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new MyFileElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((MyFileElement)(element)).KeyName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Access the collection by index
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public MyFileElement this[int index]
    {
        get { return (MyFileElement)BaseGet(index); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Access the collection by key name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public new MyFileElement this[string key]
    {
        get { return (MyFileElement)BaseGet(key); }
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MyDirElement))]
public class MyDirCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new MyDirElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((MyDirElement)(element)).RootName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Access the collection by index
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public MyDirElement this[int index]
    {
        get { return (MyDirElement)BaseGet(index); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Access the collection by key name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public new MyDirElement this[string key]
    {
        get { return (MyDirElement)BaseGet(key); }
    }
}

public class MyFileElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("keyName", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string KeyName
    {
        get { return ((string)(base["keyName"])); }
        set { base["keyName"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("copyType", DefaultValue = "")]
    public string CopyType
    {
        get { return ((string)(base["copyType"])); }
        set { base["copyType"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("sourceFileName", DefaultValue = "")]
    public string SourceFileName
    {
        get { return ((string)(base["sourceFileName"])); }
        set { base["sourceFileName"] = value; }
    }
}

public class MyDirElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("rootName", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string RootName
    {
        get { return ((string)(base["rootName"])); }
        set { base["rootName"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("rootLocation", DefaultValue = "")]
    public string RootLocation
    {
        get { return ((string)(base["rootLocation"])); }
        set { base["rootLocation"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Chooko.. thanks for the sample above.. really appreciated. This seems very similar to what I had... just wondering where the differences ly. I'll get a good look at it now in a bit. thnks

Comment: Thanks Chooko, although I needed something a bit more complex, this example provide helpful guidance to my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the MyDirectoryRoot property should be MyDirectoryRootConfigEleCollection instead of MyFileListConfiguration. Note that the add element name should be 'add' to match your sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationcollectionattribute.configurationcollectionattribute.aspx

Comment: well spotted fsimonazzi and thanks for the link. So like this...  [ConfigurationProperty("MyDirectoryRootConfigEleCollection", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
        [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MyDirectoryRootConfigEleCollection), AddItemName = "add")]
        public MyDirectoryRootConfigEleCollection MyDirectoryRoot